# How to add static routes to a desktop application that still work when running the executable?

Tags: c#, pdf, rdlc

I have a desktop application in which I have to create PDF files using Windows Report Viewer. I'm using MVVM architecture with WPF. When I want to create a PDF, I call a method from the ViewModel that calls a method that creates and save the PDF. This is the method:

```
GeneratePDF(Routes.route);
```

In my solution I have two projects, one for the ModelView and other for the View. The PDF .rdlc is stored in the View project.

I have the route stored in a class that has static strings with the routes like this:

```
public class Routes
{
    public static string route = "..\\..\\Reports\\Report.rdlc";
}
```

With this I enter in the View project folder and get the .rdlc inside the Reports folder and take the route in the GeneratePDF method like this:

```
public void GeneratePDF(route)
{
   ...
   ReportViewer viewer = new ReportViewer();
   ...
   viewer.LocalReport.ReportPath = route;
}
```

This is working well in Debug. The problem is when I create a executable for the application. When creating the executable, the folders change and the route in Routes class no longer work, I think because the .rdlc file is not longer in that path so when I try to call the CreatePDF method, it not works because it can't find the folder.

Is there a way to solve this?

Comment: C# is a general purpose programming language used to create programs of all different shapes and sizes. You'll need to be a bit more specific as to the UI technology you're using; WinForms? WebForms? ASP.NET MVC? All of these are valid targets for the report viewer, but the answer will most certainly change depending on which one you're using.

Comment: The rdlc file is usually loaded in the SQL Server Reports and has an URL.  See : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/url-access-ssrs?view=sql-server-ver15